# Using JQuery to handle the selection of dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to use JQuery to handle the selection of the input do the calculation and display the results.

```
<input type="text" id="num1"/>

<select name="Calc">
  <option value="add">ADD</option>
  <option value="subtract">SUBTRACT</option>
  <option value="multiply">MULTIPLY</option>
  <option value="divide">DIVIDE</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="num2"/>

<button id="Calculate">CALCULATE</button>
<button id="clear">CLEAR</button>
Calculated Value:
<div class="valueDisp">
<div id="calc_value">
</div>
</div>

$('input[name=Calc]').ready(function () {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    var num1 = $('#num1').val();
    var num2 = $('#num2').val();
    if (selected == 'add') var total = +num1 + +num2;
    else if (selected == 'subtract') var total = num1 - num2;
    else if (selected == 'multiply') var total = num1 * num2;
    else if (selected == 'divide') var total = num1 / num2;
    else var total = ("Please select an option");
    $("#calculate").click(function () {});
    $("#clear").click(function () {
        $('.input').val("");
    });
    $("#calc_value").html(total);
});
```

I have the following : http://jsfiddle.net/kHtHA/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this (check the value `attribute` of `select`, changed it, but there are other ways)

```
<option value="add">ADD</option>
```

become

```
<option value="+">ADD</option> <!--and so on-->
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Calculate').click(function(){
        var operand = $('select[name=Calc]').val();
        var num1 = $('#num1').val();
        var num2 = $('#num2').val();
        if(num1.match(/\d/) && num2.match(/\d/)) {
            var total = eval(num1 + operand + num2);
            $("#calc_value").html(total);
        }
    });
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/kHtHA/13/)

Answer (score 1):

Check the update : http://jsfiddle.net/kHtHA/7/

```
    var doCalculate = function () {
        var selected = $('select[name="Calc"]:eq(0)').val();
        var num1 = $('#num1').val();
        var num2 = $('#num2').val();
        if (selected == 'add') var total = +num1 + +num2;
        else if (selected == 'subtract') var total = num1 - num2;
        else if (selected == 'multiply') var total = num1 * num2;
        else if (selected == 'divide') var total = num1 / num2;
        else var total = ("Please select an option");
        $("#calc_value").html(total);
    };
    $('#Calculate').click(doCalculate);
    $('select[name="Calc"]').change(doCalculate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what you want. A fiddle update: http://jsfiddle.net/kHtHA/14/.

```
$('#Calculate').on('click', function(e){
    var num1 = parseInt($('#num1').val());
    var num2 = parseInt($('#num2').val());

    if(isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)){
        return;
    }

    var operator = $('select[name=Calc]').val();
    var total;
    switch(operator){
        case "add":
            total = num1 + num2;
            break;
        case "subtract":
            total = num1 - num2;
            break;
        case "multiply":
            total = num1 * num2;
        break;
        case "divide":
            total = num1 / num2;
            break;
    }

    $('#calc_value').html(total);
});

$('#clear').on('click', function(e){
    $('#num1').val("");
    $('#num2').val("");
});
```